# Использовать поля вместо класса

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть класс модели:

```
class AccountModelNode private constructor(val key: String, val isLeaf: Boolean) {

constructor(key: String, value: AccountCardViewModel) : this(key, true) {
    this.value = value
}

constructor(key: String, list: List<AccountModelNode>) : this(key, false) {
    this.list = list
}

var value: AccountCardViewModel? = null
    private set
var list: List<AccountModelNode>? = null
    private set
}
```

И класс AccoundCardViewModel это data class, который содержит некоторые поля:

```
data class AccountCardViewModel(
val isAutomatic: Boolean = false,
val currencyCode: String = "",
val description: String = "")
```

Как вместо класса AccoundCardViewModel в модели использовать только поля AccountCardViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правльно понял Ваш вопрос, то вот так:

```
class AccountModelNode private constructor(val key: String, val isLeaf: Boolean) {

    constructor(key: String, value: AccountCardViewModel) : this(key, true) {
        this.value = value
    }

    constructor(key: String, list: List<AccountModelNode>) : this(key, false) {
        this.list = list
    }

    private var value: AccountCardViewModel? = null

    val isAutomatic: Boolean? = value?.isAutomatic

    val currencyCode: String? = value?.currencyCode

    val description: String? = value?.description

    var list: List<AccountModelNode>? = null
        private set
}
```